# Is there any way to create an index in titan-0.4.4 without cleaning up the storage backend?

Tags: cassandra, titan, indices

I am using titan-0.4.4 + cassandra 1.2.13 as storage backend. I already have  data (vertices + edges).

I have recently introduced a new Vertex & now I want to index it on its id. Can I do that without re-creating the entire database? I don't want to clean the storage backend here. (I know this works after cleaning the storage backend & re-creating indices).

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 0.4.x you are stuck. The best you can do is create a new index with a different property key and then change your vertex to use that new property key with the index.  Other than that approach, you will need to create a new database then migrate your data to it.

Titan 0.5.x no longer has this limitation.  It is possible to alter the schema and re-index without having to migrate the data.